# How to do a full outer join excluding the intersection between two pandas dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, join, duplicates

I have two datasets with identical column headers and I would like to remove ALL data that is 100% identical, and just have what they do not have exactly in common remaining. How could I go about doing that?

[image]

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get everything BUT the intersection of two pandas datasets, try this:

```py
# Everything from the first except what is on second
r1 = df1[~df1.isin(df2)]

# Everything from the second except what is on first
r2 = df2[~df2.isin(df1)]

# concatenate and drop NANs
result = pd.concat(
    [r1, r2]
).dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
```

There is one caveat though, when filtering with boolean masks, your int values might turn into floats. By default, pandas replaces unwanted (False) values with the float version of NAN and converts the entire column to float. You can see this happening in the example below.

To circumvent this, explicitly declare the datatype when creating the dataframe.

#### Example

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv("./csv1.csv") #, dtype='Int64')
print(f"csv1\n{df1}\n")

df2 = pd.read_csv("./csv2.csv") #, dtype='Int64')
print(f"csv2\n{df2}\n")

# Everything from first except what is on second
r1 = df1[~df1.isin(df2)]
# Everything from second except what is on first
r2 = df2[~df2.isin(df1)]

# concatenate and drop NANs
result = pd.concat(
    [r1, r2]
).dropna().reset_index(drop=True)

print(f"result\n{result}\n")
```

##### Input

```
csv1
   A   B   C
0  1   2   3
1  4   5   6
2  7   8   9

csv2
    A   B   C
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6
2  10  11  12
```

##### Output

```
result
      A     B     C
0   7.0   8.0   9.0
1  10.0  11.0  12.0
```

Comment: That might work. Essentially I'm wanting to get rid of everything the two have in common and just be left with what they don't have in common. So perhaps a join might be a better answer.

Comment: My bad, I misunderstood. You wanted everything but the intersection. I will update my answer!

Comment: Thank you so much pbsb! I knew there had to be a way to do it. I will give it a shot, but looking at your explanation, it makes a lot of sense!

Comment: PBSB - thank you again! Your suggestion worked perfectly!

Comment: Nice! I'm glad I could help